# Why newly dynamically added Card components doesn't re render on form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch data from GitHub user API and store the JSON in an array, and then and then loop through the array and create Card components dynamically on submission of form, but the Card components doesn't render even though the array is updated with the newly added user.

I have added relevant code files and image of React component tree on dev console before and after valid form submission. Thanks.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Form from "./Form";
import Cardlist from "./Cardlist";
import ProfileData from "../JSON";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  testData = ProfileData();
  state = {
    profiles: this.testData,
  };
  addNewProfile = (profile) => {
    this.setState({
      profiles: [...this.state.profiles, profile],
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>GITHUB PROFILE CARDS</h4>
        <Form onSubmit={this.addNewProfile} />
        <Cardlist profiles={this.state.profiles} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Form.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default class Form extends React.Component {
  state = { userName: "" };
  handleSubmit = (event) => (
    event.preventDefault(),
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.userName}`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.props.onSubmit(data);
      })
  );
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="username"
            value={this.state.userName}
            onChange={(event) =>
              this.setState({ userName: event.target.value })
            }
          />
          <button>Add Card</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Cardlist.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

export default class Cardlist extends React.Component {
  profile = this.props.profiles.map((element) => (
    <Card key={element.id} {...element} />
  ));
  render() {
    return (<div>{this.profile}</div>);
  }
}
```

**Card.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default class Card extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div style = {{display: 'flex'}}>
                <img src = {this.props.avatar_url} style = {{width: '100px', height: '100px'}}/>
                <div>
                    <h6>{this.props.name}</h6>
                    <h6>{this.props.name}</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**component tree before**
[array before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAHUJ.png)

**component tree after**
[array after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRrXX.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your CardList component to:

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

export default class Cardlist extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      this.props.profiles.map((element) => (
        <Card key={element.id} {...element} />
      ))
    );
  }
}
```

The problem with your CardList component is that you have a class property (profile) which is initialized when the CardList component is created but the class property does not update its value when the props is updated.

PS: you can also convert your class property into a function

```
profile = () => (
    this.props.profiles.map((element) => (
      <Card key={element.id} {...element} />
    ))
  );
```

and the on render

```
render() {
    return (<div>{this.profile()}</div>);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Cardlist.js**, instead of using a class variable, directly return the mapped elements.

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

export default class Cardlist extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.profiles.map((element) => (
      <Card key={element.id} {...element} />
    ));
  }
}
```

Working demo on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j769o).

Comment: Thanks for the response, Now got the idea why re rendering don't occur

Answer (score 0):

Although your CardList is received a new props from parent and then get rerender, this.profile outside your render function, so it never get updated. Just put it inside your render function and it works fine

```
class Cardlist extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const profile = this.props.profiles.map((element) => (
      <Card key={element.id} {...element} />
    ));
    return <div>{profile}</div>;
  }
}
```

[codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-haze-65l4n?file=/src/App.js)